# Installing OpenSSL on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, openssl, wget

I am trying to install wget on my mac with brew however I keep on getting the following error: 
abmacnb01:wget-1.13 abse08$ brew install openssl

```
==> make depend
==> make
==> make test
Last 15 lines from /Users/abse08/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl/04.make:
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
../certs/demo/dsa-ca.pem: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = CA
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
../certs/demo/dsa-pca.pem: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = PCA
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = PCA
error 10 at 0 depth lookup:certificate has expired
OK
../certs/demo/pca-cert.pem: C = AU, ST = Queensland, O = CryptSoft Pty Ltd, CN= Test PCA (1024 bit)
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
C = AU, ST = Queensland, O = CryptSoft Pty Ltd, CN = Test PCA (1024 bit)
error 10 at 0 depth lookup:certificate has expired
OK
make[1]: *** [test_verify] Error 2
make: *** [tests] Error 2
READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Erlang linked to wrong OpenSSL on OSX 10.6.8     https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/47681
openssl: add 'enable-ssl-trace' option   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/45250
```

abmacnb01:wget-1.13 abse08$

Also If i look in /System/Library/OpenSSL it exists and if i run openssl version -a I get:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
built on: Jul 31 2015
platform: darwin64-x86_64-llvm
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -    fasm-blocks -O3 -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -DMD32_REG_T=int - DOPENSSL_NO_IDEA -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
OPENSSLDIR: "/System/Library/OpenSSL"
abmacnb01:wget-1.13 abse08$
```

OpenSSL seems to be a dependant for nearly package I wish to use, is there a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Before starting to install it make sure you have the right folders. The goal is to compile and install in the `/usr/local`. Make sure to if verify this folder already exists, don't panic if it does not. On El Cap it does not exist.

Let's change that by entering the following commands into terminal. The following commands just create the required folders:

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/src`

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log`

`mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

With El Cap the folks at apple introduced a new feature called System Integrity Protection, which is just a fancy way of saying it abstracts the system code a bit further build a tighter system, its cool I guess. But this means you need to modify the ownership of the `/usr/local` in order to install openSSL.

`sudo chown -R $LOGNAME:staff /usr/local`

`sudo chown $LOGNAME:staff /usr/local`

Now you have created the necessary folders Folder Structure for the installation.

Step 1: Get OpenSSL

`cd /usr/local/src`

`curl --remote-name https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz`

Now we extract the files we just downloaded in the `/usr/local/src` folder and change directory to openssl-1.0.2h:

`tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz`

`cd openssl-1.0.2h`

Step 2: Compile & Install

Now your powers as a sorcerer of computing have summoned and extracted the soul of OpenSSL onto your Metal Machine, now you must conjure (compile) and invoke (install) this ancient beast using the following spell (lines of code):

`./configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h shared`

`make depend`

`make`

`make install`

Step 3: Update Bash

The OpenSSL Deamon has awoken and now you must cast the spell of controlling it otherwise your metal machine will be confused. The following commands update your Bash Startup Script:

`echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'export MANPATH=/usr/local/openssl/ssl/man:$MANPATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Step 4: Install Certificates

It turns out even vicious demons like the one you just summoned require certificates in this paper world. So cast the following spells to give it the right certificates to work with the world:

`security find-certificate -a -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain > /usr/local/openssl/ssl/cert.pem`

and the one below

`security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain >> /usr/local/openssl/ssl/cert.pem`

Step 5: Verify Installation

Life is weird sometimes things don't always work the way despite our best intentions. Check if things worked:

`openssl version -a`

Thanks for reading, I hoped it helped! I struggled with this for a while too. Please feel free to hate/love on my attempt to add some color to the description of the solution. Also please tell me if this does not work for you, I'm curious to know. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info - still did not work !!!! - have just set up a virtual box on VMWARE now much easier !!!! - what is weird is that home-brew did not realise that openssl is already installed and I only was trying to get wget on mac !!!

Answer (score 0):

changing permissions helped me to solve this problem:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info tried that no luck still won't install !!! Thanks for trying